# PHP: Fixing encoding issues with database content - removing accents from characters

Tags: php, encoding, diacritics

I'm trying to make a URL-safe version of a string.

In my database I have a value `medúlla` - I want to turn this into `medulla`.

I've found plenty of functions to do this, but when I retrieve the value from the database it comes back as `medÃºlla`.

I've tried:

- Setting the **column** as utf_8 encoding
- Setting the **table** as utf_8 encoding
- Setting the **entire database** as utf_8 encoding
- Running `SET NAMES utf8` on the database before querying

When I echo the value onto the screen it displays as I want it to, but the conversion function doesn't see the ú character (even a simple `str_replace()` doesn't work either).

Does anybody know how I can force the system to recognise this as UTF-8 and allow me to run the conversion?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php for an explanation and examples of how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to make a URL-safe version of a string.

Whilst it is common to use ASCII-only ‘slugs’ in URLs, it is actually possible to have web addresses including non-ASCII characters. eg.:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medúlla
```

This is a valid IRI. For inclusion in a **U**​RI, you should UTF-8 and %-encode it:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Med%C3%BAlla
```

Either way, most browsers (except *sometimes* not IE) will display the IRI version in the address bar. Sites such as Wikipedia use this to get pretty addresses.

> the conversion function doesn't see the ú character

What conversion function? `rawurlencode()` will correctly spit out `%C3%BA` for `ú`, if, as presumably you do, you have it in UTF-8 encoding. This is the correct way to include text in a URL's path component. (`urlencode()` also gives the same results, but it should only be used for query components.)

If you mean `htmlentities()`... do **not** use this function. It converts all non-ASCII characters to HTML character references, which makes your output unnecessarily larger, and means it has to know what encoding the string you pass in is. Unless you give it a UTF-8 `$charset` argument it will use ISO-8859-1, and consequently screw up all your non-ASCII characters.

Unless you are specifically authoring for an environment which mangles non-ASCII characters, it is better to use `htmlspecialchars()`. This gives smaller output, and it doesn't matter(*) if you forget to include the `$charset` argument, since all it changes is a couple of characters like `<` and `&`.

(Actually it could matter for some East Asian multibyte character sets where `<` could be part of a multibyte sequence and so shouldn't be escaped. But in general you'd want to avoid these legacy encodings, as UTF-8 is less horrific.)

> (even a simple `str_replace()` doesn't work either).

If you wrote `str_replace(..., 'ú', ...)` in the PHP source code, you would have to be sure that you saved the source code in the same encoding as you'll be handling, otherwise it won't match.

It is unfortunate that most Windows text editors still save in the (misleadingly-named) “ANSI” code page, which is locale-specific, instead of just using UTF-8. But it should be possible to save the file as UTF-8, and then the replace should work. Alternatively, write `'\xc3\xba'` to avoid the problem.

> Running `SET NAMES utf8` on the database before querying

Use `mysql_set_charset()` in preference.

Comment: You were right about the text editor saving in ANSI - I resaved (in a better text editor...) in UTF-8 and everything worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To transform an UTF-8 string into an URL-safe string you should use:

```
$str = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE//TRANSLIT', $strt);
```

The IGNORE part tells `iconv()` not to raise an exception when facing a character it can't manage, and the TRANSLIT part converts an UTF-8 character into its nearest ASCII equivalent ('ú' into 'u' and such).

Next step is to preg_replace() spaces into underscores and substitute or drop any character which is [unsafe within an URL](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm), either with `preg_replace()` or `urlencode()`.

As for the database stuff, you really should have done all this setting stuff before INSERTing UTF-8 content. Changing charset to an existing table is somewhat like changing a file extension in Windows - it doesn't convert a JPEG into a GIF. But don't worry and remember that the database will return you byte by byte exactly what you've stored in it, no matter which charset has been declared. Just keep the settings you used when INSERTing and treat the returned strings as UTF-8.

Comment: I fixed the issue by re-saving the file itself in a proper UTF-8 encoding and everything worked, but thanks for the tips - I wasn't sure if changing the database encoding would have any impact on the stuff already in there, thank you for the clarification.