# Convert accented characters to their plain ascii equivalents

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, locale, diacritics

I have to convert french characters into english on my php. I've used the following code:

```
iconv("utf-8", "ascii//TRANSLIT", $string);
```

But the result for `ËËË` was `"E"E"E`.

I don't need that double quote and other extra characters - I want to show an output like `EEE`. Is there any other method to convert french to english? Can you help me to do this?

Comment: You could keep the utf-8 encoding and maintain a mapping for the accented characters to English letters.

Comment: Good question! I'm having the same problem if converting central european characters (iso-8859-2) from utf8 by `iconv("utf-8", "ascii//TRANSLIT",)`, regardless of setting various `setlocale()`. When converting from iso-8859-2 by `iconv("iso-8859-2",..)`, the problem does not exist!!

Comment: @bdares, sounds a bit like reinventing the wheel; this is the last possibility I would resort to. I feel there should be (and probably is) more systematic solution to **"de-accentization"**.

Comment: I've used utf8_decode($str).It show me ��.and used utf8_encode($str)it show me ÃÃÃ.Any idea ?

Comment: Why? This is 99% likely to be the wrong thing. You cannot "convert French to English" this way!!!

Comment: This fixed the question marks and quotes for me
`setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
$string = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);`

Answer (score 51):

The [PHP Manual iconv Intro](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.iconv.php) has a warning:

> Note that the iconv function on some systems may not work as you
> expect. In such case, it'd be a good idea to install the GNU libiconv
> library. It will most likely end up with more consistent results.

But if accented characters are the only issue then you could use a dirty strtr (partially from [strtr comments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php#98669)):

```
$string = 'Ë À Ì Â Í Ã Î Ä Ï Ç Ò È Ó É Ô Ê Õ Ö ê Ù ë Ú î Û ï Ü ô Ý õ â û ã ÿ ç';

$normalizeChars = array(
    'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ð'=>'Dj','Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A',
    'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E', 'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I',
    'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ń'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U', 'Ú'=>'U',
    'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss','à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a',
    'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c', 'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i',
    'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ń'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o', 'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u',
    'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ü'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y', 'ƒ'=>'f',
    'ă'=>'a', 'î'=>'i', 'â'=>'a', 'ș'=>'s', 'ț'=>'t', 'Ă'=>'A', 'Î'=>'I', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ș'=>'S', 'Ț'=>'T',
);

//Output: E A I A I A I A I C O E O E O E O O e U e U i U i U o Y o a u a y c
echo strtr($string, $normalizeChars);
```

Comment: If i got my string from html form(ex:ÉÉÉabcd)  and used,                                                   $this->_data = JRequest::get('post');

$string=$this->_data['quiz_optionA'];                                    Then used that convertion method the result was A�A�A�abcd..The french characters didnt coverted as a string.Output should be EEEabcd.U have any idea to do this ?

Comment: ÉÉÉabcd.This is my string,which comes from form, using post method.

Comment: After this line? `$string=$this->_data['quiz_optionA'];` If you just try and output the string as is, does it break the accented characters?

Comment: It's dirty, but it works... at least for me when converting Irish names!

Comment: missing 'ń' => 'n'

Comment: Polish special chars are missing.

Comment: Note: In German if you don't have access to the umlaut you can add an E: for example Ü becomes UE; ö becomes oe; etc. So the trick is deciding whether or not you can always do that. I don't know if this rule applies to languages other than German though and that's the problem in the first place: not everything translates okay.

Answer (score 23):

This worked for me for French characters.

```
$str = utf8_encode($str);
$str = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
```

Comment: Actually the result is not the same on Windows and on Linux.

Comment: Replaces Irish characters, such as `Í` with `?` when I tried it... is there a difference between those and French chars?

Comment: Actually, the first line converted the character to `Ã` and then the second line converted the `Ã` to `??` :/

Comment: This fixed the question marks and quotes for me
`setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
$string = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);`

Answer (score 9):

An alternative:

```
function replaceAccents($str) {

  $search = explode(",","ç,æ,œ,á,é,í,ó,ú,à,è,ì,ò,ù,ä,ë,ï,ö,ü,ÿ,â,ê,î,ô,û,å,ø,Ø,Å,Á,À,Â,Ä,È,É,Ê,Ë,Í,Î,Ï,Ì,Ò,Ó,Ô,Ö,Ú,Ù,Û,Ü,Ÿ,Ç,Æ,Œ");

  $replace = explode(",","c,ae,oe,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,y,a,e,i,o,u,a,o,O,A,A,A,A,A,E,E,E,E,I,I,I,I,O,O,O,O,U,U,U,U,Y,C,AE,OE");

  return str_replace($search, $replace, $str);
}


$str = "À é ü ä ç";
$str = replaceAccents($str);
echo "$str \n"; 
//output "A e u a c"
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is the wordpress way:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_accents

You can copy the remove_accents() function and implement to your system.

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L682

Comment: _"You can copy the remove_accents() function ..."_ I created a package by roughly copy/paste the wordpress function: https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/convert-accent-characters Hope it could help!

Comment: @rap-2-h Wordpress is licensed with GPL, correct me if I am wrong but your package should also have same license.

Comment: you can just open the file from link and rip out their character map when you scroll enough....

Comment: @Round-Sliced Could you elaborate on exactly how to 'rip out their character map' without causing internal errors? I want to keep Italian accents...

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me in this instance is using utf8_encode on the string and then using strtr() function after encoding it.

ie.

```
$normalizeChars = array(
            'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ð'=>'Dj','Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A',
            'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E', 'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I',
            'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ń'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U', 'Ú'=>'U',
            'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss','à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a',
            'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c', 'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i',
            'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ń'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o', 'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u',
            'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ü'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y', 'ƒ'=>'f',
            'ă'=>'a', 'î'=>'i', 'â'=>'a', 'ș'=>'s', 'ț'=>'t', 'Ă'=>'A', 'Î'=>'I', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ș'=>'S', 'Ț'=>'T',
        );

$legal_name = utf8_encode($res['LEGAL_NAME']);
$res['LEGAL_NAME'] = strtr($legal_name, $normalizeChars);
```

outputs = Burelle Amélie -> Burelle Amelie

Answer (score 4):

Here's what helped me. It's important to set locale to en_US and not your real locale.

```
$curLocale = setlocale(LC_ALL, 0); //gets current locale
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8"); //without this iconv removes accented letters. If you use another locale it will also fail

$text = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $text);

setlocale(LC_ALL, $curLocale); //set locale to what it was before
```

Comment: This is what I arrived at as well. `iconv()` was working fine in the console but not running in a web app which made this harder to debug.

Comment: With this the result of `iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", "äëïöüß");` is `"a"e"i"o"uss` which confuses me.

Answer (score 3):

In laravel you can simply use `str_slug($accentedPhrase)` and if you care about dash (-) that this method substitute with space you can use `str_replace('-', ' ', str_slug($accentedPhrase))`

Comment: `str_slug` also supports a `$separator` parameter so you can do `str_slug($accentedPhrase, ' ')` as a shortcut

Answer (score 2):

Just putting here as an alternative (a bit more complex in nature), wordpress uses this function for accent removal. Made some changes below to make it run indepndently without referencing wordpress functions.

```
     function mbstring_binary_safe_encoding($reset = false)
{
    static $encodings  = array();
    static $overloaded = null;

    if (is_null($overloaded)) {
        $overloaded = function_exists('mb_internal_encoding') && (ini_get('mbstring.func_overload') & 2);
    }

    if (false === $overloaded) {
        return;
    }

    if (!$reset) {
        $encoding = mb_internal_encoding();
        array_push($encodings, $encoding);
        mb_internal_encoding('ISO-8859-1');
    }

    if ($reset && $encodings) {
        $encoding = array_pop($encodings);
        mb_internal_encoding($encoding);
    }
}

function seems_utf8($str)
{
    mbstring_binary_safe_encoding();
    $length = strlen($str);
    mbstring_binary_safe_encoding(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $c = ord($str[$i]);
        if ($c < 0x80) {
            $n = 0;
        }
        // 0bbbbbbb
        elseif (($c & 0xE0) == 0xC0) {
            $n = 1;
        }
        // 110bbbbb
        elseif (($c & 0xF0) == 0xE0) {
            $n = 2;
        }
        // 1110bbbb
        elseif (($c & 0xF8) == 0xF0) {
            $n = 3;
        }
        // 11110bbb
        elseif (($c & 0xFC) == 0xF8) {
            $n = 4;
        }
        // 111110bb
        elseif (($c & 0xFE) == 0xFC) {
            $n = 5;
        }
        // 1111110b
        else {
                return false;
            }
            // Does not match any model
            for ($j = 0; $j < $n; $j++) {
                // n bytes matching 10bbbbbb follow ?
                if ((++$i == $length) || ((ord($str[$i]) & 0xC0) != 0x80)) {
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    function remove_accents($string)
{
        if (!preg_match('/[\x80-\xff]/', $string)) {
            return $string;
        }

        if (seems_utf8($string)) {
            $chars = array(
                // Decompositions for Latin-1 Supplement
                'ª' => 'a', 'º'  => 'o',
                'À' => 'A', 'Á'  => 'A',
                'Â' => 'A', 'Ã'  => 'A',
                'Ä' => 'A', 'Å'  => 'A',
                'Æ' => 'AE', 'Ç' => 'C',
                'È' => 'E', 'É'  => 'E',
                'Ê' => 'E', 'Ë'  => 'E',
                'Ì' => 'I', 'Í'  => 'I',
                'Î' => 'I', 'Ï'  => 'I',
                'Ð' => 'D', 'Ñ'  => 'N',
                'Ò' => 'O', 'Ó'  => 'O',
                'Ô' => 'O', 'Õ'  => 'O',
                'Ö' => 'O', 'Ù'  => 'U',
                'Ú' => 'U', 'Û'  => 'U',
                'Ü' => 'U', 'Ý'  => 'Y',
                'Þ' => 'TH', 'ß' => 's',
                'à' => 'a', 'á'  => 'a',
                'â' => 'a', 'ã'  => 'a',
                'ä' => 'a', 'å'  => 'a',
                'æ' => 'ae', 'ç' => 'c',
                'è' => 'e', 'é'  => 'e',
                'ê' => 'e', 'ë'  => 'e',
                'ì' => 'i', 'í'  => 'i',
                'î' => 'i', 'ï'  => 'i',
                'ð' => 'd', 'ñ'  => 'n',
                'ò' => 'o', 'ó'  => 'o',
                'ô' => 'o', 'õ'  => 'o',
                'ö' => 'o', 'ø'  => 'o',
                'ù' => 'u', 'ú'  => 'u',
                'û' => 'u', 'ü'  => 'u',
                'ý' => 'y', 'þ'  => 'th',
                'ÿ' => 'y', 'Ø'  => 'O',
                // Decompositions for Latin Extended-A
                'Ā' => 'A', 'ā'  => 'a',
                'Ă' => 'A', 'ă'  => 'a',
                'Ą' => 'A', 'ą'  => 'a',
                'Ć' => 'C', 'ć'  => 'c',
                'Ĉ' => 'C', 'ĉ'  => 'c',
                'Ċ' => 'C', 'ċ'  => 'c',
                'Č' => 'C', 'č'  => 'c',
                'Ď' => 'D', 'ď'  => 'd',
                'Đ' => 'D', 'đ'  => 'd',
                'Ē' => 'E', 'ē'  => 'e',
                'Ĕ' => 'E', 'ĕ'  => 'e',
                'Ė' => 'E', 'ė'  => 'e',
                'Ę' => 'E', 'ę'  => 'e',
                'Ě' => 'E', 'ě'  => 'e',
                'Ĝ' => 'G', 'ĝ'  => 'g',
                'Ğ' => 'G', 'ğ'  => 'g',
                'Ġ' => 'G', 'ġ'  => 'g',
                'Ģ' => 'G', 'ģ'  => 'g',
                'Ĥ' => 'H', 'ĥ'  => 'h',
                'Ħ' => 'H', 'ħ'  => 'h',
                'Ĩ' => 'I', 'ĩ'  => 'i',
                'Ī' => 'I', 'ī'  => 'i',
                'Ĭ' => 'I', 'ĭ'  => 'i',
                'Į' => 'I', 'į'  => 'i',
                'İ' => 'I', 'ı'  => 'i',
                'Ĳ' => 'IJ', 'ĳ' => 'ij',
                'Ĵ' => 'J', 'ĵ'  => 'j',
                'Ķ' => 'K', 'ķ'  => 'k',
                'ĸ' => 'k', 'Ĺ'  => 'L',
                'ĺ' => 'l', 'Ļ'  => 'L',
                'ļ' => 'l', 'Ľ'  => 'L',
                'ľ' => 'l', 'Ŀ'  => 'L',
                'ŀ' => 'l', 'Ł'  => 'L',
                'ł' => 'l', 'Ń'  => 'N',
                'ń' => 'n', 'Ņ'  => 'N',
                'ņ' => 'n', 'Ň'  => 'N',
                'ň' => 'n', 'ŉ'  => 'n',
                'Ŋ' => 'N', 'ŋ'  => 'n',
                'Ō' => 'O', 'ō'  => 'o',
                'Ŏ' => 'O', 'ŏ'  => 'o',
                'Ő' => 'O', 'ő'  => 'o',
                'Œ' => 'OE', 'œ' => 'oe',
                'Ŕ' => 'R', 'ŕ'  => 'r',
                'Ŗ' => 'R', 'ŗ'  => 'r',
                'Ř' => 'R', 'ř'  => 'r',
                'Ś' => 'S', 'ś'  => 's',
                'Ŝ' => 'S', 'ŝ'  => 's',
                'Ş' => 'S', 'ş'  => 's',
                'Š' => 'S', 'š'  => 's',
                'Ţ' => 'T', 'ţ'  => 't',
                'Ť' => 'T', 'ť'  => 't',
                'Ŧ' => 'T', 'ŧ'  => 't',
                'Ũ' => 'U', 'ũ'  => 'u',
                'Ū' => 'U', 'ū'  => 'u',
                'Ŭ' => 'U', 'ŭ'  => 'u',
                'Ů' => 'U', 'ů'  => 'u',
                'Ű' => 'U', 'ű'  => 'u',
                'Ų' => 'U', 'ų'  => 'u',
                'Ŵ' => 'W', 'ŵ'  => 'w',
                'Ŷ' => 'Y', 'ŷ'  => 'y',
                'Ÿ' => 'Y', 'Ź'  => 'Z',
                'ź' => 'z', 'Ż'  => 'Z',
                'ż' => 'z', 'Ž'  => 'Z',
                'ž' => 'z', 'ſ'  => 's',
                // Decompositions for Latin Extended-B
                'Ș' => 'S', 'ș'  => 's',
                'Ț' => 'T', 'ț'  => 't',
                // Euro Sign
                '€' => 'E',
                // GBP (Pound) Sign
                '£' => '',
                // Vowels with diacritic (Vietnamese)
                // unmarked
                'Ơ' => 'O', 'ơ'  => 'o',
                'Ư' => 'U', 'ư'  => 'u',
                // grave accent
                'Ầ' => 'A', 'ầ'  => 'a',
                'Ằ' => 'A', 'ằ'  => 'a',
                'Ề' => 'E', 'ề'  => 'e',
                'Ồ' => 'O', 'ồ'  => 'o',
                'Ờ' => 'O', 'ờ'  => 'o',
                'Ừ' => 'U', 'ừ'  => 'u',
                'Ỳ' => 'Y', 'ỳ'  => 'y',
                // hook
                'Ả' => 'A', 'ả'  => 'a',
                'Ẩ' => 'A', 'ẩ'  => 'a',
                'Ẳ' => 'A', 'ẳ'  => 'a',
                'Ẻ' => 'E', 'ẻ'  => 'e',
                'Ể' => 'E', 'ể'  => 'e',
                'Ỉ' => 'I', 'ỉ'  => 'i',
                'Ỏ' => 'O', 'ỏ'  => 'o',
                'Ổ' => 'O', 'ổ'  => 'o',
                'Ở' => 'O', 'ở'  => 'o',
                'Ủ' => 'U', 'ủ'  => 'u',
                'Ử' => 'U', 'ử'  => 'u',
                'Ỷ' => 'Y', 'ỷ'  => 'y',
                // tilde
                'Ẫ' => 'A', 'ẫ'  => 'a',
                'Ẵ' => 'A', 'ẵ'  => 'a',
                'Ẽ' => 'E', 'ẽ'  => 'e',
                'Ễ' => 'E', 'ễ'  => 'e',
                'Ỗ' => 'O', 'ỗ'  => 'o',
                'Ỡ' => 'O', 'ỡ'  => 'o',
                'Ữ' => 'U', 'ữ'  => 'u',
                'Ỹ' => 'Y', 'ỹ'  => 'y',
                // acute accent
                'Ấ' => 'A', 'ấ'  => 'a',
                'Ắ' => 'A', 'ắ'  => 'a',
                'Ế' => 'E', 'ế'  => 'e',
                'Ố' => 'O', 'ố'  => 'o',
                'Ớ' => 'O', 'ớ'  => 'o',
                'Ứ' => 'U', 'ứ'  => 'u',
                // dot below
                'Ạ' => 'A', 'ạ'  => 'a',
                'Ậ' => 'A', 'ậ'  => 'a',
                'Ặ' => 'A', 'ặ'  => 'a',
                'Ẹ' => 'E', 'ẹ'  => 'e',
                'Ệ' => 'E', 'ệ'  => 'e',
                'Ị' => 'I', 'ị'  => 'i',
                'Ọ' => 'O', 'ọ'  => 'o',
                'Ộ' => 'O', 'ộ'  => 'o',
                'Ợ' => 'O', 'ợ'  => 'o',
                'Ụ' => 'U', 'ụ'  => 'u',
                'Ự' => 'U', 'ự'  => 'u',
                'Ỵ' => 'Y', 'ỵ'  => 'y',
                // Vowels with diacritic (Chinese, Hanyu Pinyin)
                'ɑ' => 'a',
                // macron
                'Ǖ' => 'U', 'ǖ'  => 'u',
                // acute accent
                'Ǘ' => 'U', 'ǘ'  => 'u',
                // caron
                'Ǎ' => 'A', 'ǎ'  => 'a',
                'Ǐ' => 'I', 'ǐ'  => 'i',
                'Ǒ' => 'O', 'ǒ'  => 'o',
                'Ǔ' => 'U', 'ǔ'  => 'u',
                'Ǚ' => 'U', 'ǚ'  => 'u',
                // grave accent
                'Ǜ' => 'U', 'ǜ'  => 'u',
            );

            $string = strtr($string, $chars);
        } else {
            $chars = array();
            // Assume ISO-8859-1 if not UTF-8
            $chars['in'] = "\x80\x83\x8a\x8e\x9a\x9e"
                . "\x9f\xa2\xa5\xb5\xc0\xc1\xc2"
                . "\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca"
                . "\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd1\xd2"
                . "\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd8\xd9\xda"
                . "\xdb\xdc\xdd\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3"
                . "\xe4\xe5\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb"
                . "\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf1\xf2\xf3"
                . "\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb"
                . "\xfc\xfd\xff";

            $chars['out'] = "EfSZszYcYuAAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyy";

            $string              = strtr($string, $chars['in'], $chars['out']);
            $double_chars        = array();
            $double_chars['in']  = array("\x8c", "\x9c", "\xc6", "\xd0", "\xde", "\xdf", "\xe6", "\xf0", "\xfe");
            $double_chars['out'] = array('OE', 'oe', 'AE', 'DH', 'TH', 'ss', 'ae', 'dh', 'th');
            $string              = str_replace($double_chars['in'], $double_chars['out'], $string);
        }

        return $string;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this:

```php
$cadena = "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞ
    ßàáâãäåæçèéêëEËËËìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûýýþÿŔŕ";

$cadena =  iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT',$cadena);

echo $cadena;
```

Result:

```
AAAAAAAECEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYTH
    ssaaaaaaaeceeeeEEEEiiiidnoooooouuuyythyRr
```