# TCPDF - missing Swedish characters

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF in Codeigniter to generate PDF file.

I have link from 'view' to 'controller' function that contains parameters. One parameter is **name = 'Högskolan'**.
When I get this parameter in controller and display in PDF sometimes it's displayed like 'Högskolan', sometimes like 'Hgskolan'(missing swedish character). This issue happens only in IE (sometimes - not always).

Also there are differences when I save this file with **File->Save as** and **File->Save**.
With first option the file is saved as 'Hgskolan.pdf', with the second as 'Högskolan.pdf'.

What can caused these issues? Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: It could be browser differences regarding to default character set. Try using urlencode.

Comment: Thanks ... it's solved the problem with IE (parameter is shown correct).

Comment: But I still can't save the file correctly.                            How can I add some encoding inside the Output function (tcpdf function)?                               Output(urlencode('Högskolan').'.pdf', 'I') - displays HC3B6gskolan.pdf                                                      Output('Högskolan.pdf', 'I') - displays Hgskolan.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing something like this: [Convert accented characters to their plain ascii equivalents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054818/convert-accented-characters-to-their-plain-ascii-equivalents)

You will find it works better to output without the accents (provided it doesn't substantially change the word of course).

As anttir suggested it's probably a browser specific issue or system issue not liking the characters.  Can you test output on another browser or another platform to isolate the issue.

I'm not 100% sure if it's TCPDF tripping you up there, or the browser.  You can test that with something like Fiddler (http://fiddler2.com/) or Charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com/) [both debugging proxies].