# Convert text to hyphen-separated string (slug) including other custom replacements

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace, slug

I want to make a hyphen-separated string (for use in the URL) based on the user-submitted title of the post.
Suppose if the user entered the title of the post as:

```
$title = "USA is going to deport indians -- Breaking News / News India";
```

I want to convert it as below

```
$slug = usa-is-going-to-deport-indians-breaking-news-news-india";
```

There could be some more characters that I also want to be converted. For Example '&' to 'and' and '#', '%', to hyphen(-).

One of the ways that I tried was to use the `str_replace()` function, but with this method I have to call `str_replace()` too many times and it is time consuming.

One more problem is there could be more than one hyphen (-) in the title string, I want to convert more than one hyphens (-) to one hyphen(-).

Is there any robust and efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried preg_replace ?

Comment: They usually called "slug"s, search for this and it will yield relevant results.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305879/automatic-clean-and-seo-friendly-url-slugs?lq=1

Answer (score 8):

You can use `preg_replace` function to do this :

**Input :**

```
$string = "USA is going to deport indians -- Breaking News / News India";

$string = preg_replace("/[^\w]+/", "-", $string);
echo strtolower($string);
```

**Output :**

```
usa-is-going-to-deport-indians-breaking-news-news-india
```

Comment: Thanks. But will it convert '&' to 'and' and '#', '%' to '-'. Please read my question fully.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `sanitize_title()` function
check the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title/)

Answer (score 0):

There are three steps in this task (creating a "slug" string); each requires a separate pass over the input string.

1. Cast all characters to lowercase.
2. Replace ampersand symbols with `[space]and[space]` to ensure that the symbol is not consumed by a later replacement AND the replacement "and" is not prepended or appended to its neighboring words.
3. Replace sequences of one or more non-alphanumeric characters with a literal hyphen.

Multibyte-safe Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bpJF6))

```
$title = "ÛŞÃ is going to dèport 80% öf indians&citizens are #concerned -- Breaking News / News India";

echo preg_replace(
         '/[^\pL\pN]+/u',
         '-',
         str_replace(
             '&',
             ' and ',
             mb_strtolower($title)
         )
     );
```

Output:

```
ûşã-is-going-to-dèport-80-öf-indians-and-citizens-are-concerned-breaking-news-news-india
```

Note that the replacement in `str_replace()` could be done within the `preg_replace()` call by forming an array of find strings and an array of replacement strings.  However, this may be false economy -- although there would be fewer function calls, the more expensive regex-based function call would make two passes over the entire string.

If you wish to convert accented characters to ASCII characters, then perhaps read the different techniques at [Convert accented characters to their plain ascii equivalents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10054818/2943403).

If you aren't worries about multibyte characters, then the simpler version of the same approach would be:

```
echo preg_replace(
         '/[^a-z\d]+/',
         '-',
         str_replace(
             '&',
             ' and ',
             strtolower($title)
         )
     );
```

To mop up any leading or trailing hyphens in the result string, it may be a good idea to unconditionally call `trim($resultstring, '-')`. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/Mi3pX)

For a deeper dive on the subject of creating a slug string, read [PHP function to make slug (URL string)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2955251/2943403).