# Check if string contains these special chararters

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure what these characters are called, i think they are foreign chars but i could be wrong.

Some of them exist in my MySQL database and when returning the rows, i want to either fix the characters to become there normal version

```
turn ø into o
turn å into a
```

if that can't be done then i want to check if the string contains any of these characters so i can then block that string from being displayed.

Any help will be appreciated thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054818/convert-accented-characters-to-their-plain-ascii-equivalents

Comment: SELECT REPLACE('Bøb', 'ø', 'o');#Bob  , but the major problem seems how do they get into your database, if not wanted?

Comment: It's a search query database that a client wants me to search through to gather some information on user searches, he obviously allowed these characters in his search feature, i'm not sure how many of them exist so i couldn't do it this way.

Comment: what if it's an address from [Å, Tranøy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85,_Tran%C3%B8y)