# Replace multi UTF-8 chars with one same acs ii char by preg_replace()

Tags: php

I have to convert a UTF-8 string to non UTF-8 string, I want to replace:

**Ậ,Ẫ,Ẩ,Ầ,Ấ,Â,Ặ,Ẵ,Ẳ,Ằ,Ắ,Ă,Ạ,Ã,Ả,À,Á** to **A**,

**Ự,Ữ,Ử,Ừ,Ứ,Ư,Ụ,Ũ,Ủ,Ù,Ú** to **U**,

**Ợ,Ỡ,Ở,Ờ,Ớ,Ơ,Ộ,Ỗ,Ổ,Ồ,Ố,Ô,Ọ,Õ,Ỏ,Ò,Ó** to **O**... and much more with same case

By php `preg_replace()` ?

May I use ?:

```
$string = preg_replace('/Ậ,Ẫ,Ẩ,Ầ,Ấ,Â,Ặ,Ẵ,Ẳ,Ằ,Ắ,Ă,Ạ,Ã,Ả,À,Á/', 'A', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/Ợ,Ỡ,Ở,Ờ,Ớ,Ơ,Ộ,Ỗ,Ổ,Ồ,Ố,Ô,Ọ,Õ,Ỏ,Ò,Ó/', 'O', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/Ự,Ữ,Ử,Ừ,Ứ,Ư,Ụ,Ũ,Ủ,Ù,Ú/', 'U', $string);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing accented characters php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php)

Comment: no, that posts useless with me, i just want to use `preg_replace()` and not all UTF-8 chars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, if you remove the `,`, place everything inside a character class, and add the `/u` modifier if the input string is UTF-8. Example:

```
preg_replace('/[ỰỮỬỪỨƯỤŨỦÙÚ]/u', 'U', $string);
```

You can also use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace):

```
str_replace(array('Ự', 'Ữ', ...), 'U', $string);
```

or [`strtr()`](http://php.net/strtr):

```
strtr($string, 'ỰỮỬ', 'UUU');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since regular expressions aren't the optimal way of solving this, may I hint at PHPs [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) facilities:

```
$string = 'ỬỪỨƯỤ';

// temporarily switch locale
$locale = setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.UTF-8');
// use iconv to transliterate
$string = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $string);
// restore locale
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, $locale);

// $string is now "UUUUU"
```

Comment: While this is a great idea, it doesn't always come with the expected result. For example, "aÎâa" gets translated as "a^I^aa". It probably depends on other factors as well, since "ỬỪỨƯỤ" for me gets translated as "".

Answer (score 0):

I've only done this in Java once, but in php the trick will be similar.

In unicode, if you normalize, a diacritic is encoded using [combining diacritical marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks) i.e. one letter and one symbol. Just drop the symbol and you're done.

```
private static final Pattern DIACRITIC =
        Pattern.compile("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}\\p{IsLm}\\p{IsSk}]+");


public static String replaceCombiningDiacriticalMarks(String text) {
    return DIACRITIC.matcher(Normalizer.normalize(text, Normalizer.Form.NFKD)).replaceAll("");
}
```

If you also have characters from other alphabets, or mathematical symbols, things get trickier. It's still possible to replace them with pure ascii (like a √ with a v for example), but it gets arbitrary which character to pick.