# Removing a single quote out of a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, wordpress, preg-replace

I'm trying to remove the ' out of my string.

Here's my code:

```
$page_title = strtolower(wp_title( '', false, 'right' ));
echo $page_title;
echo "<br/>";
$clean = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $page_title);
echo $clean;
```

Output:

```
regio’s 
regio8217s
```

Why does it return 8217 instead of ''?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not getting the same result you do: http://codepad.org/Ir5ZIsLk

Comment: The `’` is inserted using the character reference `&#8217;`.

Comment: Hi Alex-Info.net, that's because you used the static string.

Like @Gumbo said, the ' is inserted using the character reference.

Any idea how we can remove that certain character?

I'm learning by the minute... :)

Answer (score 1):

Your quote has been converted to its unicode value (`&#8217;`) (see [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm) for example). It's a special character, not a standard one.

Comment: The OP asked why, which is the question I answered.  Though fair point.  A solution would depend on where the OP wanted the problem addressed - when the value's stored, or when it's retrieved

Comment: I want the ' to be removed out of the string.

Comment: You could use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) explicitly, replacing '&#8217;' with '' before your `preg_replace`.  The problem with that is it's not very generic - you could get other escaped characters in there.  Maybe `preg_replace(/&[^;]+;/, '', $page_title);` would be better.  But it's still open to problems

Comment: Mhm that's right. Let's try "carré" for example.

That preg_replace statement throws an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting ')'

Comment: Glad to help; I updated my comment before I saw yours.  `str_replace` only handles the single quote case - you might want a `preg_replace` if there are other characters you need to handle

Comment: Sorry, I've been away.  The problems with typing code without being able to test.  I think I missed the quotes around the regex: `preg_replace('/&[^;]+;/', '', $page_title);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/u', '', $page_title);`

the u after the pattern processes unicode characters too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But it doesn't work... It keeps returning "regio8217s"

Comment: I assume you're viewing this output in a web browser, right? Do a view-source on those results and see if it's really the raw unicode character in there, or really the HTML-encoded version.

Comment: You may need to do an additional replacement specifically to look for and replace HTML-encoded unicode characters, like preg_replace('/&#[0-9]+;/g', '', $page_title);

Comment: It outputs this in the browser:

<div id="menu">
<ul>
regio&#8217;s  
<br/>regio8217s
</ul>
</div>

Comment: Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g'

Comment: Ah yes, PHP's preg_replace is global by default, so there's no need for the "g" after the pattern.

Comment: This preg_replace statement only addresses the single quote, I want all unicode symbols to be removed. For example carré --> carre

Comment: That's an entirely different task. Now you're talking about replacing accented characters with their unaccented equivalents: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php