# PHP remove characters with hyphens above them like (é)

Tags: php, string, character

Is there any possible way of doing this in PHP? Eg convert the word Québec

```
$str = 'Québec';

echo convert($str);
```

result:

```
Quebec
```

Comment: These are actually accented letters, that may have made it tougher for you to search for! Check out the answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php - basically, you can use [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) to replace them.

Answer (score 0):

Those are called [diacritics (or accents)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic). The process of converting some text from one script to another (e.g. one with diacritics to one without) is called [transliteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration) and PHP [has a module for performing it](http://php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php).

You probably want something like:

```
transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII', $your_input);
```