# PHP Replace Accents

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this code:

```
$accents = ["/[Àà]/", "/[ÈÉèé]/", "/[Ìì]/", "/[Òò]/", "/[Ùù]/"];
$replacement = ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U"];
$to_be_replaced = preg_replace($accents, $replacement, $to_be_replaced);
```

It is intended to replace all accents (only the ones used in italian) with unaccented letters.

I tried with this:

```
$to_be_replaced = 'ò'; #first try
$to_be_replaced = 'èàò'; #second try
```

But I get this output:

> 1: AO
>
> 2: AEAAAO

So it seems to be adding an 'A' everytime before right replace, but I can't really figure out why.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your encoding is messed up. That's why.

Comment: You might want to use this approach instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3371773/421752

Comment: @Im0rtality I used iconv() and I finally solved it so...
Thank You!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing accented characters php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php)

Answer (score 3):

Encoding.

Try adding the `u` modifier to your regexes, ie `"/[Àà]/u"`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `str_replace`

```
<?php
    $string="Àkkk";
    $from = explode (',', "À,È,É,Ì,Ò,Ù,ç,æ,œ,á,é,í,ó,ú,à,è,ì,ò,ù,ä,ë,ï,ö,ü,ÿ,â,ê,î,ô,û,å,e,i,ø,u");
    $to = explode (',',"A,E,E,I,O,U,c,ae,oe,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,y,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u");
    echo str_replace ($from, $to, $string);
?>
```