# PHP Error Message: preg_match

Tags: php, regex, function, preg-match, offset

I just created a website, and I wanted to create a "search" module, the database was created, and I get connected, the system seems to work except this message which covers my web page:

PHP Error Message:

```
Warning: preg_match () [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: unknown property name Effective \ P or \ p at 

offset 7 in / home/a3637125/public_html/Moteur-de-recherche/class.inc/moteur-php5.class-inc.php on line 706
```

The relevant code:

```
if(preg_match('#[\p{Xan}][^a-zA-Z]#iu', $mot)) {
  $mot = str_ireplace($withaccent, $withnoaccent, htmlspecialchars(trim($mot)));
}
```

Comment: Well your regex is broken, but i have no idea what you are trying to achieve with it

Answer (score 2):

Your pcre version is too old and doesn't know the unicode character class `\p{Xan}`. This is not really a problem since you can write:

```
#[\pL\pN][^a-z]#i
```

That does exactly the same.

Nota Bene: It will be interesting if you explain what your pattern is supposed to do. If you are trying to replace all accentued characters with an ascii equivalent, I suggest to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I solved the problem fairly quickly, indeed, that's right, just replace the expression like this:' if(preg_match(‘#[a-zàáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûü][^a-zA-Z]#iu’, $mot)) '