# Replacing accent or wrong cast PHP

Tags: php, string, non-ascii-characters

When trying to make a JS chat I got stuck in a problem with accented charactes.
Their names are gotten from Mongodb with PHP and then sent to the view and js like that:

```
$name = $user['id']['info']['first_name']; //Éric
$c = mb_detect_encoding($name, mb_detect_order(), true);
$name = iconv($c,'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $name);
var username = "<?php echo $name; ?>" // Displays ric
```

I tried sugestions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php), mostly works only if string set mannualy, like:

```
$name = 'á|â|à|ä';
...
var username = "<?php echo $name; ?>" // Displays a|a|a|a
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try htmlentities or utf8_encode?

Comment: IIRC, without `ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE` iconv will fail (return '') on un-tranlitarable chars

Comment: @Naruto, none worked, but html_entity_decode solved the problem, it was returning &Eacute already Thanks

Comment: No problem, it had to be an encoding problem :)

Comment: Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26514376/192024 it has the solution