# Replacing special characters of items in array, PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, ascii, non-ascii-characters

Let's say I have following string: `$string = "Ne, želim ići kući."`

Then I split it with `preg_split("/[\s,.]+/",$string)` and get an array with every word in the sentence: `Array ( [0] => [1] => e [2] => želim [3] => ići [4] => kući [5] => )`

How can I now (for every array item) replace all the special characters into standard ascii ones?

Is there an easier method to replace characters like ***ć*** and others than the following?

```
foreach ($array as $element) {
    echo str_replace("ć","c",$element);
    ...
}
```

Or is there maybe a function which can handle the whole array by itself without any foreach-loops; something like `convert_to_ascii($array)`

Edit: Because I want to omit the for loop, I think this question is not a duplicate as flagged. My question is regarding a function which can handle and return whole arrays by itself.

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26514376/2162347) answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing accented characters php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php)

Comment: [`echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

Comment: @Dragos that answer still uses a for loop, I would like to omit that if possible; and because of not wanting such a loop this question is *not* a duplicate

Comment: The question IS a duplicate, you do have there the solution to how to replace the accented characters.
How you then apply that is a matter of using array functions like [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

Comment: What's wrong with using a loop for this? Any function you find will almost sure contain a loop; if you just want the syntactic sugar of a clean function call, write a function that loops over the array and replaces your characters.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO a nicer way to get this job done is to install / enable the native PHP module called **translit**.

For information, you can visit [pecl translit](https://pecl.php.net/package/translit).

Once you've enabled it, you can do something fancy like:

```
echo Transliterator::transliterate('àéô');
```

and you get `aeo`.

For more information, you can have a look at [here](http://php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php).