# str_replace with "grave" accent

Tags: php

I'm developing a web and I want to print some information from DB. I have found the problem that information with "grave" accent it is not possible to convert to upper case.

For example, I have the following information: John Seràn Mollò and I need to convert it to upper case. This should be the result: JOHN SERÀN MOLLÒ

I'm trying the following code:

```
            $filtre = array("&agrave", "&egrave", "&ograve");
            $modificacions = array("a", "e", "o");
            $phrase = str_replace($filtre, $modificacions, $vols[$i]['crew']);
            var_dump($phrase);
            echo strtoupper($phrase); ?>
```

In that case, the result should be JOHN SERAN MOLLO (without the accents), but I get this: JOHN SERàN MOLLò.

What I'm doing bad? How can I get JOHN SERAN MOLLO (without accents) or, if it's possible, how can I could get JOHN SERÀN MOLLÒ (accents in upper case).

Comment: `à` and `a` is not the same. add `à` to the `$modifications` array

Comment: Why don't you replace directly `à` with `À` etc... ? (if encoding is consistent in your appli)

Comment: Why are you comparing entities to a string? Surely, that's the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: I know, but if I do it I get à. I have explained below the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing accented characters php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php)

Comment: @Script47 I have the same explanation why is not working, but how can I fix it?

Comment: *How can I get JOHN SERAN MOLLO (without accents)* vs *how can I could get JOHN SERÀN MOLLÒ (accents in upper case).* - Which one do you want or do you want both? Please clarify.

Comment: Have you tried `mb_strtoupper` instead?

Comment: @Script47 I prefer to get the second one, but it doesn't matter if I can get the first one because the second one is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your installation has the [mbstring](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) extension loaded (most do, in my experience), you should be able to use [`mb_strtoupper`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php), e.g.

```
echo mb_strtoupper($phrase);
```

This will use the default internal encoding by default, so should be all you need, but you may also need to provide a second argument to specify the string encoding.

If the function isn't available, there's a polyfill available here: https://github.com/symfony/polyfill-mbstring

Answer (score 0):

Use strtoupper()  function or  mb_strtoupper() function. Woohaa just try this... Have a good Day... Seeya...

```
<?php

setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'de_DE.UTF8');

echo strtoupper('Umlaute äöü in uppercase'); // outputs "UMLAUTE äöü IN UPPERCASE"
echo mb_strtoupper('Umlaute äöü in uppercase', 'UTF-8'); // outputs "UMLAUTE ÄÖÜ IN UPPERCASE"

?>
```