# Escape special chars in PHP

Tags: php, escaping, html-entities

How can I escape 'special chars' in PHP, regardless of in which enc-type they are? Like so:

INPUT: `ë, &euml;`

OUTPUT: `e, e`

I hope someone can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `htmlentities()`

Comment: You don’t want _escaping_ here in the first place, according to the examples you have given – what you have described, is _substitution_ of characters by _other_ characters.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Might be worth showing us what you've tried and what error you are getting

Answer (score -1):

Try starting with this:

```
function replace_accents($str) {
   $str = htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
   $str = preg_replace('/&([a-zA-Z])(uml|acute|grave|circ|tilde);/','$1',$str);
   return html_entity_decode($str);
}
```

This function will convert all the accented chars into normal ones.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/rOcbE

Comment: I've specified this regards 'accented chars' (not entity), it was just to start with a direction

Answer (score -1):

did some quick coding for this.

```
<?php 

function correctWord($val) {
    return iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT', html_entity_decode($val));
}

echo correctWord("ë, &euml;");
```

found the fix in  accented character from this [Replacing accented characters php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php/3371773#3371773)

Comment: ... doesn't that basically make this question a duplicate? Should you not have just voted to close instead of answering?

Comment: i think its not duplicate since this question is asking for the special character. and other is replacing accented characters.