# How to convert special unicode character to it's closest ASCII in PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem when user input a string in special Unicode like  and my system cannot distinguish it with the string "tuyendung" that is written in ASCII. The question is how can I normalize the input string to ASCII before storing it in the database?

Sample Input:

> 

(Char code: 0xd835, 0xde01, 0xd835, 0xde02, 0xd835, 0xde06, 0xd835, 0xddf2, 0xd835, 0xddfb, 0xd835, 0xddf1, 0xd835, 0xde02, 0xd835, 0xddfb, 0xd835, 0xddf4)

Expected output:

> tuyendung

(Char code: 0x74, 0x75, 0x79, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x64, 0x75, 0x6e, 0x67)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing accented characters php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the `//TRANSLIT` option can do the trick here.

```php
<?php

$input = '';
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'US-ASCII//TRANSLIT', $input);
```

This turns (what I think are?) math symbols like  to t

Comment: Thank you very much! That is what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "tuyendung" is.

But in php, you can convert the character sets with the "iconv" function or you can keep the original form in a blob field in the database. You can make any transformation you want in the screening.

Maybe it gives an idea.