# take associative index with accent on an array

Tags: php

i try to take data from an array but it doesn't recognize the acents.

```
public function model(array $row)
{

    return new Dato([
        'name'     => $row['nombre_completo'],
        'pedido'        => $row['curso_de_interes'], 
        'hora_contacto'  => $row['horario_de_contacto'],
        'email'    => $row['correo_electrónico'], 
        'telefono'     => $row['número_de_teléfono'],

    ]);
}
```

the data came from a csv archive, the problem is in $row['correo_electrónico'] and $row['número_de_teléfono']. It doesn recognize de acents.

I try to use "correo_electr\u00f3nico" instead of "correo_electrónico" but still failing

**UPDATE**

i just ignore de acents, and it work fine

i use "correo_electronico" instead of "correo_electrónico"

thanks alot

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php/3373364#3373364) might help.

Answer (score 0):

that looks like an encoding issue, you need to figure out what encoding you are using in your code and what is used in the row indexes.
Then you have to convert the encoding to match your need.

try

```
foreach($row as $key => $value) echo $key . ' is encoded as ' . mb_detect_encoding($key) . " <BR>\n";
echo 'your code is encoded as ' . mb_detect_encoding('número_de_teléfono');
```

if `mb_detect_encoding()` doesn't work you can try with `iconv_get_encoding()`

then you can convert the encoding to what you need `mb_convert_encoding()` or `iconv()`